# How to prevent printing/saving of a file if certain cells are not modified in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a template worksheet in Excel in which I change certain cells all the time.
The question is: is there a way to make Excel prevent me from printing or saving the sheet if some cells are not changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that will trigger before saving.

Then if criteria are not met then cancel the save.

See example below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _ 
        Cancel as Boolean) 
    a = MsgBox("Do you really want to save the workbook?", vbYesNo) 
    If a = vbNo Then Cancel = True 
End Sub
```

You can also do the same before printing:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean) 
    a = MsgBox("Do you really want to print the workbook?", vbYesNo) 
    If a = vbNo Then Cancel = True 
End Sub
```

The part below will need to be amended to fit your criteria.

```
a = MsgBox("Do you really want to print the workbook?", vbYesNo) 
If a = vbNo Then Cancel = True
```

These will need to put in the 'This Workbook' and not in a module.

Comment: i have a question regarding this: when i run the macro manually it shows the message, but when i hit ctrl+p it doesn't. why and how do i fix it? @PeterH

Comment: @anne I forgot to say, these macros need to be in the 'ThisWrokbook' part not in their own modules. Then when pressing CTRL-P if you click OK/Print, the macro will then be triggered